# C++/CLR linking a static library to a dynamic library

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I am trying to link two libraries together. One is a dynamic library, the other is a static library. They are both compiled with /clr /MD.

I want to reference the static library inside the dynamic library. So I added the static library as a reference to the dynamic library.

As a POC the static library only has one class + function:

```cpp
// PacketCommunicationX.h:
#pragma once
using namespace System;
namespace PacketCommunicationX {
    public ref class PackX{public:
        void MyFunc();
    };
}

// PacketCommunication.c:
#include "PacketCommunicationX.h"
void PacketCommunicationX::PackX::MyFunc(){}
```

The dynamic library only has one free function:

```cpp
// Source.cpp:
#include "PacketCommunicationX.h"

void Func(PacketCommunicationX::PackX^ r){
    r->MyFunc();
}
```

When I compile the dynamic library I get the following error:

> 1>Source.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) PacketCommunicationX.PackX::MyFunc
> 1>*path*\Release\UsePackX.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

And I am at a loss to how and why this is happening...

Comment: C++/CLI does not support managed code in a static library, a .NET assembly is the only usable scenario.  You'd then also strongly favor an assembly reference instead of a .h file.

Comment: Ahw man, really? Well, got to look for a workaround then :-/

Comment: @HansPassant - I agree with that observation, but have yet to find official documentation. When building a static library, "ref classes" appear to in fact go into the library, but are not recognized by other C++/CLI modules at link time.